# OAuth2 , PHP and Quickbooks

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I went through the Intuit instructions to install the SDK and then just modified the CustomerQuery.php file to reflect the CLientID/Secret and tokens etc I got from the Dashboard and Keys sections but when the PHP runs I get this error

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught QuickBooksOnline\API\Exception\SdkException: [0]: cURL error during making API call. cURL Error Number:[7] with error:[Failed to connect to sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com port 80: Connection refused] thrown in C:\inetpub\vhosts\default\htdocs\teststuff\qb502\src\Core\HttpClients\CurlHttpClient.php on line 122

Any clues ?

Comment: i just fixed this this morning. for me, there was a proxy issue. Error 7 is that it just cant connect to the server

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message